# React native - Returning a string after this.props

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-props

I'm a complete begginer in React native and javascript in general.
I need to return a combination of two props inside a component.
I have a data prop in a JSON format and a string prop that represent what im supposed to return from the data.

```
_displayText = (id) => {
   var text = this.props.selectedRows[id].label
   const {data} = this.props
   return(......)
}
```

So here the text variable contains something like "pv_id_workstream.label".
Is it possible to return something like data.(the result of text) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return data[text]` is probably what you are looking for.